# mongoid how can i change a value for all company expect one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I use this to change the value for all company , i need the change for all company except one.help please

```
    irb(main):006:0>  aplayerversion = PlayerVersion.find_by(name: "4.4")

    Company.all.each do | comp |
    comp.player_version = aplayerversion
    comp.save
    end
```

i used this as solution but it doesn't work

```
   Company.all.where(:company_id.ne => "53272dee7dc8c6b77b000021").each do | comp |
   comp.player_version = aplayerversion
   comp.save
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `find_each` for things like that.. prevents that your whole db is loaded into your RAM.

I think a solution would be something like this?

```
Company.find_each do | comp |
  comp.update!(player_verison: aplayerversion) unless <your_expression>
end
```

Replace `<your_expression>` with an expression like `comp.name == "excluded"`

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to skin the same cat. This one uses a cursor & an atomic update (no callbacks will be triggered):

```
Company.where(:company_id.nin => ['53272dee7dc8c6b77b000021']).each{|l| l.set(player_version: aplayerversion) }
```